# Deep redirecting back: (history.go(-N)) with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

Simple Rails redirecting:

```
redirect_to :back
```

Now I want to redirect to page that was preprevious (`history.go(-N)`)

How can I do it?

Comment: hmm why do you need to do this? just curious.

Comment: I am lazy to send referer with form because sometimes I need just to redirect to some page from where I came to this form. It is just for administrative uses.

Comment: i see. sending the referrer would be the 'best practice' in this case i guess.

Comment: Best practice is to know all possibilities :) and use them in right moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about rendering a small template which contains something like this:

```
#controller

render 'back'

#back.js.erb
$(function() {
 history.go(-1);
});
```

Not the most elegant solution but it should work. Also the history is kept on the browser side, and i'm not sure that you can access easily on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to :back
```

in rails work by redirecting the user to whatever the URL the browser sent in the

```
HTTP_REFERER
```

header. Rails know how to redirect the user to 'back' because the browser sends the necessary information. But the browser doesn't send anything about the page before the previous referrer URL. So i don't think what you ask for is possible.

Comment: I think so as well :) Browser history is on the client side. But I just want to be sure if there are not any HTTP options which I don't know